# How to configure schema name for sql queries

Tags: activemq-classic

Is it possible to configure schema name for SQL queries generated by ActiveMQ ?

I would like to have queries like: `select * from myschema.ACTIVEMQ_MSGS...` instead of `select * from ACTIVEMQ_MSGS...`

I could set default schema for my PostgreSQL user, but this is not really professional....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `BasicDataSource`, you can use `connectionInitSqls` to select schema at connection opening (works on Oracle):

```
<bean id="postgres-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    ...
    <property name="connectionInitSqls">
        <list>
            <value>SET SCHEMA 'myschema'</value>
        </list>
    </property>
 value=""/>
</bean>
```

Or you can configure the statements produced by ActiveMQ:

```
  <persistenceAdapter>
    <journaledJDBC ...>
      <statements>
        <statements tablePrefix="myschema."/>
      </statements>
    </journaledJDBC>
  </persistenceAdapter>
```

Comment: I've tried tablePrefix but I've got syntax error - are you sure that it should work?

Answer (score 0):

I have asure SQL Server and I solved it with the following code:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://YYY.database.windows.net;databaseName=XXX;user=ZZZ@YYY;password=TTT;authenticationScheme=dbo";

    BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
    bds.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    bds.setUrl(connectionUrl);
    bds.set...
```